# Annualized rolling volatility?

Tags: volatility, annualized, rolling

I have 600 days of closing prices of a stock. I want to calculate the annualized volatility for 6 day window. How do i do that?

If I calculate the std dev of the first 6 days, i get, say 1%. This is the daily volatility of the first 6 days. To annualize it, should i just multiply 1% with sqrt(252)? Or, is this 1% the daily volatility of 6 days? In that case i should multiply with sqrt(252/6)? Is this number 1% the daily volatility for 1 day, or is it the dayily volatility for 6 days?

I dont get it, I am missing a parameter. The period should also be involved in the calculation, right?

So to annualize 6 day volatility, i multiply with sqrt(252/6)? And when do i multiply with sqrt(252)?

UPDATE1: Ami44 writes that the correct procedure to annualize a 6 day window, is to multiply with sqrt (252/6). See
[Converting 30day annualized vol to 2day annualized vol](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46765/converting-30day-annualized-vol-to-2day-annualized-vol/46821#46821)

UPDATE2: in the answer below, ForeignVolatility says that I should multiply with sqrt (252). This is contradictory to "UPDATE1" above. So I am confused. Should I multiply with sqrt (252) or sqrt(252/6)? And, if I have a 30 day window, should I still multiply with sqrt (252), or should I use sqrt(252/30)? Great confusion. Some say Ba, and other say Bu.

Comment: Ami44 writes: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/46765/converting-30day-annualized-vol-to-2day-annualized-vol/46821#46821

that the correct procedure is to get the annualized volatility for this 6 day window, by multiplying with sqrt (252/6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We work in annual units because $T=1$ means one year. This means that the time units must be converted to portions of a year. For example, in the case of daily observations, $\Delta t = 1 / 252$. Hence, in your example, we multiply by $\sqrt{252}$ because it's assumed that the variance is measured daily.

More generally, say you have $n$ returns observed with frequency $\Delta t$ arbitrary. Assume they are i.i.d. and follow a distribution $N(0,\sigma^2\Delta t)$. You then have
$$
\mathbb E\left[\frac 1n \sum_{t=1}^n r_t^2\right] 
= \frac 1n \sum_{t=1}^n\mathbb E\left[r_t^2\right]
= \frac 1n \sum_{t=1}^n\sigma^2\Delta t
= \sigma^2\Delta t.
$$
What you described, the sdt dev of the first 6 days, corresponds to the square-root to an estimation of the LHS with $n=6$. The value you're looking for is $\sigma^2$. Hence, you need to multiply by $1/\sqrt{\Delta t} = 1/(1/\sqrt{252}) = \sqrt{252}$.

Comment: You do not need to assume normality for your argument to go through.

Comment: @OrvarKorvar, ForeignVolatility is right. Other sources may be wrong.

Comment: @RichardHardy Ok, thanx! So if I do a rolling vol of 30 days, I still multiply with sqrt(252)? It does not matter which window size I use, I always multiply with sqrt (252)?

I think it was great that this is cleared up, because other sources say something else. People will be confused. Let ut clear up the confusion on this question! :)

Comment: @OrvarKorvar, I think ForeignVolatility's answer does a good job of explaining things.

Comment: @RichardHardy Haha! Someone else wrote the same thing; some theory and "I think it is obvious what you should do". Well, if it was obvious then people would not be so confused on this? As you say, there is great confusion on this. I have tried to get an answer to this, to clear up the confusion. But people write "it is obvious". That does not decrease the confusion. I, and many more, are still confused. So you say that I should always multiply with sqrt(252) no matter the window size? I can just discard the window size?

Comment: @OrvarKorvar, I did not say there was great confusion on this. Anyway, the safest approach is to actually understand things. Then you will not have to rely on rules of thumb. Since I do not have  time to contribute an answer that is more elaborate than the current one, I will leave it at that.

Comment: I understand, thanx for the time you put in though. 
If anyone else can chime in? Why are there lot of posts where people write you should annualize with sqrt(252/6)? And other people write sqrt (252)? There are several questions regarding this matter. "Other sources may be wrong" - that proves there is great confusion on this. Can we clear this up?

Comment: @OrvarKorvar the number you multiply by depends on the frequency of the sampling ($\Delta t)$, not on the number of observations ($n$). This is because, by computing std dev, you are already taking the number of observations out of the equation.

Comment: @ForeignVolatility Ok, thanx for the answer, finally! I had to read lot of threads on annualized vol, and ask lot of questions, and spend many hours on this question. This was helpful. Thanx again! If every question was answered with "think a bit, it is obvious" there would be no reason to have this site.
But why are people answering with SQRT(252/6) in several threads? When do we need to multiply with SQRT(252/6) and when do we use SQRT(252)?

Comment: Because they’re probably summing the squared returns instead of taking the mean of them.